# Expressing volume of bounded solid as iterated integral(s)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to express $\iiint_E f(x,y,z) \ dV$ as an iterated integral.

The solid is bounded by the surfaces $y^2+z^2=9$, $x=-2$, $x=2$.

Looking at the projection on the plane x=0, the trace is a circle with radius 3 and center $(y,z)=(0,0)$. So $[(y,z)|-3\leq y\leq 3, -\sqrt{9-y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-y^2}]$

This would give the iterated integral:

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\int_{-2}^{2} \ dx\ dz\ dy$$

In a similar way, I came up with the following variations of the integral:

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_{-2}^{2} \ dx\ dy\ dz$$

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}} \ dy\ dx\ dz$$

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}} \ dy\ dz\ dx$$

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \ dz\ dx\ dy$$

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \ dz\ dy\ dx$$

Have I created the bounds on the integrals correctly, and are these all the ways to form the iterated integral?

Comment: Did you mean z=-2 and z=2? x=-2 and x=2 does not make sense to me, I think you will have infinite volume.

Comment: @matt I had a typo in the equation of the cylinder. Fixed now.

Comment: @statematics yes these are all correct and all the possible orders in cartesian coordinates. Then of course there are cylindrical coordinates, spherical coordinates... :)

Comment: You can enforce cylindrical coordinates with respect to the $yz-$plane to make your bounds simpler. Doing so generates the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3 \int_{-2}^{2}rf(x,r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$ But this isn't the question you asked. You want to express your integral as an iterated integral, which would be as $$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \int_{-2}^{2} \int_0^{f(x,y,z)}\mathrm{d}w\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y$$